# force dhcp server to always run

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dhcp, dhcp-server

I have an Ubuntu machine with two Ethernet network interfaces and on one of them I am running a **DHCP server** (`isc-dhcp-server`).

I noticed that the server daemon stops running whenever I suspend the machine and then I turn it on again.

Can I force the DHCP server to **always run** without any manual intervention (i.e. `sudo service isc-dhcp-server restart`)?

Comment: It hadn't stop on a suspension, there is some problem with your system. Maybe you could quickfix it.

Comment: If you don't need the server, shut it down and don't suspend it to avoid problems. Suspend really should only be used on client hardware, never on servers.

Comment: @SvW There are cases if a server needs to be periodically suspended, and it is part of its normal day-to-day work. For example if it is running in a car. I admit it is the case not very often.

Comment: All right, thank you SvW. Now I know. Your remark is what I was looking for.

Comment: @PeterHorvath: Then you must specifically make sure that the services are working in that environment. Stock installs of usual server operating systems and services are not configured for this by default.

Comment: You can use configuration management to ensure the service is always running. CFEngine is my favourite.